# Need a way to properly determine c data type sizes from within python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

The company I work for has a proprietary file format that's old.  REALLY old.  I'm building a python library to read/write from the files (database type files) and have some questions.

The runtime that originally reads/writes to the files reads out the first XX bytes dynamically based on the `sizeof` the struct in question.  For example:

```
struct fhdr {
    union {
        unsigned char ifflag[2]; /* file type and psw */
        int     fh_flag;         /* alignment to old version */
    } ufh;
    unsigned    reclen;          /* record length in bytes */
    DWORD       fsize;           /* byte size/reclen */
    struct {
        short   typ;
        short   offset;          /* in bytes */
    } fmt[MAXITMS];              /* struct for formatted file */  (65?)
};
```

My issue is that we have customers across a wide array of platforms.  A `long` on one customer is 8 bytes, but a customer on an old SCO 6 box (they're out there!) might be 4 bytes in size.

Right now, I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf("char=%d\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("int=%d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("short=%d\n", sizeof(short));
    printf("long=%d\n", sizeof(long));
    printf("float=%d\n", sizeof(float));
    printf("double=%d\n", sizeof(double));
    printf("long double=%d\n", sizeof(long double));
    printf("DWORD=%d\n", sizeof(long));
    printf("unsigned=%d\n", sizeof(unsigned));
    return 0;
}
```

It just prints out the sizes in this format:

```
char=1
int=4
short=2
long=8
float=4
double=8
long double=16
DWORD=8
```

and it's parsed when the class is instantiated.  I can then go and build an array based on the platform's real variable sizes.

My question is:  Is there a way, in python 3.x, for me to find an individual server's data type sizes or am I just better off parsing a simple c program as above?

It's not hard, it just feels tedious and repetitive and feels WRONG to go and create custom functions to retrieve each datatype.

```
header_fields = {
    'ifflag': IMS.char() * 2,
    'fh_flag': IMS.int(),
    'reclen': IMS.unsigned(),
    'fsize': IMS.DWORD(),
    'typ': IMS.short(),
    'offset': IMS.short()
}
```

(yes, I know that a char is always 1 byte.  I just like uniformity.)

What I have works and it does it's job rather well.  I just want to learn how to improve on it, if possible.

Comment: There is no "C"  or "server" data type size. It is specific to the compiler used.

Comment: Ah...  I think I see what you mean.  What I really need to look at are the specs of the machine that compiled the runtime to begin with.

Comment: Don't you need the `sizeof`s of the machine _and_ _compiler_ that created the file in the first place, rather than those of the machine/compiler running your Python code? Or is it always the same machine?
In any event, the Python runtime's primitives' sizes aren't necessarily helpful.

Comment: No, the Python runtime's primitives aren't helpful, but that's what `struct.unpack()` or `bitstring` is for.  Edit:  Yes, you are apparently correct on your statement about the compiling machine as clarified by @EugeneSh above.  I very much appreciate your reply!